# Is Wake On LAN supposed to work even after AC power reset?

Tags: port-forwarding, wake-on-lan, gigabit-ethernet, acpi, arp

So, if you unplug the AC power cable from the wall and re-connect it to the PC Power Supply, is the Wake On Lan functionality still supposed to work on a PC?

The WoL functionality is enabled in Bios and Adapter properties/Power Management/Advanced Properties.

In my machine, WoL works if there are no power disruptions, but if the main power to the PC is turned off and later turned on (or the main power is disrupted/reset), it is not waking up using magic packets.

I can see even after you unplug the power cable and plug back in, the NIC LED light keeps flashing as if it is working. But, it just doesn't wake the computer.

Additional Note: I am using GA-Z77X-UD5H motherboard and using the Intel GbE port on windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Gaming PC with an ASUS Z97A and I was just about to get to the same conclusion.
In my case, I had to wait for a while, maybe time enough for the NIC to get its MAC populated into the Switch MAC Address table.

Try it again, but wait for 1 or 2 minutes before trying to send the magic packet and see if it helps solving your problem.